# PostgreSQL Join Flatten Result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've begun to maintain a PSQL database that stores data used by researchers for various analyses. I was asked to query this database and provide the results such that all the (one-to-many) joined records appear as separate columns instead of rows.

I found an approach that worked, but it required a lot of manual work. I had to figure out ahead of time the maximum number of child records for the parent, and write out a huge `select_list`.

Does anyone know a better/dynamic way than this? I'd even take a non-psql approach. My actual query had way more fields and joins than this.

```
Select parentA, parentB, parentC
childC[1] AS childC_1, childD[1] AS childD_1,     
childC[2] AS childC_2, childD[2] AS childD_2,     
childC[3] AS childC_3, childD[3] AS childD_3,     
childC[4] AS childC_4, childD[4] AS childD_4,     
childC[5] AS childC_5, childD[5] AS childD_5,     
childC[6] AS childC_6, childD[6] AS childD_6,     
childC[7] AS childC_7, childD[7] AS childD_7,     
childC[8] AS childC_8, childD[8] AS childD_8,     
childC[9] AS childC_9, childD[9] AS childD_9,     
childC[10] AS childC_10, childD[10] AS childD_10, 
childC[11] AS childC_11, childD[11] AS childD_11, 
childC[12] AS childC_12, childD[12] AS childD_12, 
childC[13] AS childC_13, childD[13] AS childD_13, 
childC[14] AS childC_14, childD[14] AS childD_14, 
childC[15] AS childC_15, childD[15] AS childD_15, 
childC[16] AS childC_16, childD[16] AS childD_16, 
childC[17] AS childC_17, childD[17] AS childD_17, 
childC[18] AS childC_18, childD[18] AS childD_18, 
childC[19] AS childC_19, childD[19] AS childD_19, 
childC[20] AS childC_20, childD[20] AS childD_20, 
From
(
    Select 
        p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC,
        array_agg(c.childC) as childC, array_agg(c.childD) as childD, 
    From childTable c
    RIGHT JOIN parentTable p ON p.parentA=c.childA AND p.parentB=c.childB
    GROUP BY p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC
) as r1
```

(The researchers needed the data in this format so they could analyze the data in excel)

Edit: Here is a mockup of the tables for this example and the output I'm looking for:

```
Parent Table:
[parentA, parentB, parentC]
1, "John", "Nurse"
2, "Sam", "Developer"
3, "Bob", "Teacher
4, "Susan", "Ceramicist"

Child Table:
[childA, childB, childC, childD]
1, "John", "Went to school", "10:30am"
1, "John", "Went to the store", "5:30pm"
2, "Sam", "Went to school", "4:30pm"
3, "Bob", "Went to school", "4:30pm"
3, "Bob", "Went to the mall", "6:30pm"
3, "Bob", "Went to the bar", "9:30pm"
4, "Susan", "Went to school", "4:30pm"

Wanted Result:
[parentA, parentB, parentC, childC_1, childD_1, childC_2, childD_2, childC_3, childD_3]
1, "John", "Nurse", "Went to school", "10:30am", "Went to the store", "5:30pm"
2, "Sam", "Developer, "Went to school", "4:30pm"
3, "Bob", "Teacher", "Went to school", "4:30pm", "Went to the mall", "6:30pm", "Went to the bar", "9:30pm"
4, "Susan", "Ceramicist", "Went to school", "4:30pm"
```

Comment: It is appreciated if you post an smaller example of sample data with desired output

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I added a mockup of the data, hope it helps!

Comment: in your example `parantC` is in output but not in table `parent`. `parentA`, `parentB` in output but not in child table. please correct the sample

Comment: @AkhileshMishra I fixed the issues. `parentA`/`parentB` are joined on `childA`/`childB`, I realized I forgot to convert that part of the example correctly.

Comment: Added answer with example. Hope this will help you. Let me know in case further clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approach you can follow:

1. Use below function which will generate above query. use that query and get the result.

```
create function func() returns  text
as
$$
declare
final_query text;
count_ int;
begin
select max(con) into count_ from (
select p.parentA, p.parentB, count(*) "con" from parentTable p left join childTable c  ON p.parentA=c.childA AND p.parentB=c.childB group by 1,2) tab;
final_query:='select parentA, parentB, parentC';
for i in 1.. coalesce(count_,0) loop
final_query:=concat(final_query,', childC[',i,'] AS childC_',i,', childD[',i,'] AS childD_',i);
end loop;

final_query:=concat(final_query,' from
(
    Select 
        p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC,
        array_agg(c.childC) as childC, array_agg(c.childD) as childD 
    From childTable c
    RIGHT JOIN parentTable p ON p.parentA=c.childA AND p.parentB=c.childB
    GROUP BY p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC
) as r1');
return final_query;
end;
$$

language plpgsql
```

Simply call it like below:

```
select * from func();
```

2. Use cursor returning function with dynamic query like below:

```
create function func1() returns  refcursor
as
$$
declare
final_query text;
count_ int;
ref_cursor REFCURSOR := 'mycursor';

begin

select max(con) into count_ from (
select p.parentA, p.parentB, count(*) "con" from parentTable p left join childTable c  ON p.parentA=c.childA AND p.parentB=c.childB group by 1,2) tab;
final_query:='select parentA, parentB, parentC';
for i in 1.. coalesce(count_,0) loop
final_query:=concat(final_query,', childC[',i,'] AS childC_',i,', childD[',i,'] AS childD_',i);
end loop;

final_query:=concat(final_query,' from
(
    Select 
        p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC,
        array_agg(c.childC) as childC, array_agg(c.childD) as childD 
    From childTable c
    RIGHT JOIN parentTable p ON p.parentA=c.childA AND p.parentB=c.childB
    GROUP BY p.parentA, p.parentB, p.parentC
) as r1');
open ref_cursor for execute final_query;
return ref_cursor;
end;
$$

language plpgsql
```

and call above cursor like below for the results

```
BEGIN;
SELECT func1();
FETCH all   from  mycursor; 
COMMIT;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=db288f763b242b68244c026d29f2faa2)

Comment: Thanks for this! I was hoping for some simpler functionality I was just not seeing, but since that doesn't exist I'll end up doing one of these two next time.